# Unexpected result from an if() statement processing my own function

Tags: php, function, if-statement

Never ran into this before, but is there a problem testing a user-written function within an if() statement?

I have the following in a separate PHP includes file located on a different server (called "myPhpInclude.php"):

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

function displayIt($phrase = NULL) {
    if (is_null($phrase)) return false;
    else return true;
}

if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '123.456.789.012') { /* my ip address */
    echo 'include file is coming in ok...';
}

?>
```

Excerpt from my HTML document on a separate server from the PHP includes file:

```
<?php include('http://mydomain.com/includes/myPhpInclude.php'); /* the displayIt() function is contained in this include file */ ?>

...

<div id="content">
<?php if (displayIt('on')) { /* <-- MY PROBLEM ORIGINATES HERE */?>
    <p>Some content.</p>
<? } ?>
</div>
```

The web page stops rendering at the point of my if() statement and returns no errors. PHP error debugging is activated and on.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `short_open_tag` enabled?  `<?php if (displayIt('on)) { ?>`

Comment: and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`.

Comment: Yep, short tags are good. You have an excerpt of the problematic script. I do have the errors for debugging turned on already.

Comment: Updated my PHP includes file to show the 2 other parts that aren't culprits in the failure. I have an echo only to confirm to myself that my include is working -- which it is.

Comment: Do you have the php and the html in the same file?

Comment: No @jeroen I do not. I revised my Original Question to reflect the include file relationship.

Comment: @Dr.DOT see edit to my answer, I think the issue is that you're calling http://..../myfile.php, not ./includes/path-to/my-file.php (file path vs URL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the include file:

```
include('http://mydomain.com/includes/myPhpInclude.php');
```

will request the file `includes/myPhpInclude.php` from the server `http://mydomain.com` via a normal http request. What you will receive is not php code but the output from the web-server when it runs that php file. And that even under certain conditions:

> Windows versions of PHP prior to PHP 4.3.0 do not support access of remote files via this function, even if allow_url_fopen is enabled.

What you need to do, is include the file via the local filesystem, using a relative path (or an absolute path to the file system), like for example:

```
include 'includes/myPhpInclude.php';
```

Comment: @Dr. DOT The output from that file (in this case your `echo` statement) will be included, not the original code itself.

Comment: Let me give it a shot locally and I'll post back @jeroen. The main reason I am housing the include script on a separate server is that it will have global utility and use for many of my other scripts down the road -- some of them residing on separate servers. So my intention was to write this 1 function and use it across my application enterprise. Looks like that plan of attack may not work, but I will post back shortly. Thanks for being perceptive on that jeroen.

Comment: @Dr. DOT That is possible, but then you would have to call it like `include('http://mydomain.com/includes/myPhpInclude.php?your_variables');` and have it return for example json or serialized data that you process in the calling page.

Comment: That was it @jeroen...I learned something new today. It's a good day when you learn new things! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wait wait wait, do you have $phrase and $phase? I think it's a typo.

There:

```
function displayIt($phrase = NULL) { <== phrase
    if (is_null($phase))             <== phase
```

If not, try putting it in a try{} block, try `echo displayIt('on');`, maybe it returns false for some reason.

**Edit**: instead of `include('http://mydomain.com/includes/myPhpInclude.php');` try `include('./includes/myPhpInclude.php');` or replace it with the filesystem path of the included file.

Even if cross_domain_include was effective, fetching the php file from the url wouldn't give you the php code, but rather the output (which would be empty in this case).

Comment: It was a typo. Thanks for pointing out @LukaRamishvili. I corrected my original question

Answer (score 1):

You spelled "phrase" wrong in the second variable.

Comment: Good catch @JeremyLawson. fixed it in my original question.